# The following classes could not be found: - android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub

Tags: android, android-studio, adt, wear-os

I get this error in my project on Android Studio when trying using Android Wear:

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> - android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Which causes those errors:

> Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'rectLayout' in
>   package...
>
> Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute
>   'roundLayout' in package...

How could I fix this? thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details about what IDE you are using, and what kind of code are you trying to compile?

Comment: Android studio, the "Hello World" app of the android wear.

Comment: Are you on Android Studio 8.0 or 8.1? Please update to 8.1 because 8.0 had some problems with the examples.

Answer (score 3):

There's an unofficial UI library that is automatically included when you create your wearable app with the Android Studio Project Wizard. You can also add the library to your build.gradle file with the following dependency declaration:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

I created a build.gradle file under the build folder, added these dependencies lines, and all is well.

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#UiLibrary

Comment: Wish someone had a solution for same error using eclipse.  I have all the libs in the projects just something is not right when app runs.

Comment: It seems in Android Studio V1.1.0 these dependencies are automatically added, however you still get the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio V1.1.0, after creating a new project with an Android Wear module, the dependencies are automatically added to the build.gradle file, however the problem still exists.

There are prompts to try building the project or fixing the build file but these do not work.

**FIX**

Close the project and reopen it.

Comment: I had the same situation recently, but instead of closing the project I was able to fix it by just hitting the "Sync project with Gradle files" button.  It's the one that looks like a little soccer ball with a down arrow coming out of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to update to the latest Android Studio 0.8.1. When you download Android Studio, it will be 0.8.0, so you need to immediately let it install the updates. There were some bugs in the examples in 0.8.0 that 0.8.1 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

@JPM I had the same problem.

By checking the "Problems" tab (at the bottom panel), I saw that the application could not find the jar "wearable-1.0.0/bin/wearable-1.0.0.jar". In order to create this file, I did the following:

1. At the properties of the wearable-1.0.0 project I checked **is Library** and that the **Build Target** is **Android 4.4W**
2. I Build the wearable-1.0.0 project again (right click -> Build Project)

So, this created the bin directory as well as the jar file and I was able to run my Wear Application at my samsung watch

I hope this helps